# Customise Font style of Title and Subtitle in Notification in swift

Tags: ios, swift, unnotificationscontentextension

Hey Devs I have been working on **Customised Notifications**. For that I have **NotificationContentExtension** for **customisation of UI**. I am able to customize almost UI part but **unable to change font of Title, Subtitle** Label with **SF-Pro Text** Font.

**Note:-** I have added **SFProText** in Project Info.plist and its working fine in Project but In **Notifications its now working**.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: have you set font target for both extension and project ?

Comment: Thanks @RajaKishan You saved me. Its working

Comment: @RajaKishan I also have attachment which shows image in right side of Notifications. But sometimes it doesnt appear speacially when i kill app. Do you know anything about it?